# Fill contingency table based on total variable

Tags: r

I have a list of stores and I have a product (apples). I ran a system of linear equations to get **the column 'var'; this value represents the amount of apples you will receive or have to give to another store**. I can't figure out how to make an 'actionable dataframe' from it. I can't figure out the correct terms to correctly explain what I want so I hope below helps:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(store = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), 
                 sku = c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'), 
                 var = c(1,4,-6,-1,5,-3))
```

[image]

Output I want (or something similar):

```
output <- data.frame(store = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), sku = c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'), var = c(1,4,-6,-1,5,-3), ship_to_a = c(0,0,1,0,0,0), ship_to_b = c(0,0,4,0,0,0), ship_to_c = c(0,0,0,0,0,0), ship_to_d = c(0,0,0,0,0,0), ship_to_e = c(0,0,1,1,0,3), ship_to_f = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

[image]

*Bonus: Ideally, I would like to fill the ship_to_store columns until all (-)minus values are 'gone' when sum(df$var) doesn't count up to zero.*

Comment: Where did you get this information from ship_a to ship_f? Where are we supposed to get it? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Store A needs to receive 1 apple. Store B needs to receive 4 apples. Store C needs to ship 6 apples. Thus store C can ship 1 to store A and 4 to B, then they have 1 left to ship and store E still needs 5, thus they send 1 there. Etc. The amount you need to receive or ship is in column 'var'.

Comment: Does it matter what stores give to which other stores? I.e does store f have to give its 3 apples to e or can it give to b?

Comment: Does not matter. Just as long as eventually all 'give' (minus var) stores end up filling the other stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution. It relies on there being a net zero of each sku.

If that's the case, then we should be able to line up all the donated items (one row for each unit in the negative `var`s, sorted by sku) with all the received items (one row for each positive `var`, sorted by sku).
Consequently, the first 5 donated apples are matched with the first 5 received apples, and so on.

Then we total up the total for each sku between each donor and recipient pair and spread so each recipient gets a column.

#### Edit: corrected sign and added `complete` to match OP solution

```
library(tidyverse)
output <- bind_cols(

  # Donors, for whom var is negative
  df %>% filter(var < 0) %>% uncount(-var) %>% select(-var) %>%
    arrange(sku) %>% rename(donor = store),

  # Recipients, for whom var is positive
  df %>% filter(var > 0) %>% uncount(var) %>% 
    arrange(sku) %>% rename(recipient = store)) %>%

  # Summarize and spread by column
  count(donor, recipient, sku) %>%
  complete(donor, recipient, sku, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  mutate(recipient = paste0("ship_to_", recipient)) %>%
  spread(recipient, n, fill = 0)


> output
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  donor sku   ship_to_a ship_to_b ship_to_c ship_to_d ship_to_e ship_to_f
  <fct> <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a     apple         0         0         0         0         0         0
2 b     apple         0         0         0         0         0         0
3 c     apple         1         4         0         0         1         0
4 d     apple         0         0         0         0         1         0
5 e     apple         0         0         0         0         0         0
6 f     apple         0         0         0         0         3         0
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works nicely but I thought I would add one that approaches the problem as a linear programming problem. This would be helpful if

1. You need to scale the problem to a large number of stores or
2. You end up deciding that there are genuine cost differences between shipping from store a to store f versus store a to store b and you want a minimal cost solution

The structure of your problem is a linear programming problem known as the transport problem. Yours is a tidy case where: 1. it costs the same to move a good from any sender to any receiver and 2. your system is balanced insofar as demand = supply.

The easiest way to think about the constraints on the solution to the problem is (I think) in terms of the matrix of places that are sending goods versus those receiving them. We can make that matrix from your toy example:

```r
# Load the data
df <- data.frame(store = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), 
                 sku = c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'), 
                 var = c(1,4,-6,-1,5,-3))
df
#>   store   sku var
#> 1     a apple   1
#> 2     b apple   4
#> 3     c apple  -6
#> 4     d apple  -1
#> 5     e apple   5
#> 6     f apple  -3

# Seeing the row-column constraints
sol.mat <- matrix(c(1,4,1,0,0,1,0,0,3), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rownames(sol.mat) <- -1 * df$var[df$var < 0]
colnames(sol.mat) <- df$var[df$var >= 0]
sol.mat
#>   1 4 5
#> 6 1 4 1
#> 1 0 0 1
#> 3 0 0 3
```

What this matrix shows us is that the solution to the system you have proposed satisfies the constraints that all of the row sums equal the amount to be sent from each store and all the column sums equal the amount to be received. Any solution needs to meet those criteria. Thus if we have S senders (the rows) and R receivers (the columns) we have SxR unknowns. If we call each unknown `x_ij` where `i` indexes the sender and `j` the receiver we have the constraints that (A) `sum_j x_ij = S_i` and (B) `sum_i x_ij = R_j`. In a normal transport problem we would also have a cost associated with each link between a sender and receiver. This will be an SxR matrix, that we can call C. We would then seek the solution that minimizes costs, and solve numerically with `min sum_i sum_j x_ij * c_ij`, subject to (A) and (B).

The fact that costs don't figure in your discussion just means all routes cost the same. We can still use this same structure of the problem to solve for a solution using the existing libraries R has for linear programming. I'm going to use the package `lpSolve` which has a function for solving precisely this kind of problem called `lp.transport`. Below I write a 
wrapper function around `lp.transport` that takes your known values and the store names and determines a valid solution. The function can also take a user supplied cost matrix (SxR), and can return output either in the compact form of a SxR matrix or as the larger matrix you are hunting for:

```r
get_transport_matrix <- function(vals, labels, costs = NULL, bigmat = TRUE) {
  if (sum(vals) != 0) {stop("Demand and Supply are Imbalanced!")}
  S <- -1 * vals[which(vals < 0)]
  names(S) <- labels[which(vals < 0)]
  R <- vals[which(vals >=0)]
  names(R) <- labels[which(vals >=0)]

  if (is.null(costs)) {
    costs.mat <- matrix(1, length(S), length(R))
  } else {
    costs.mat <- costs
  }

  solution <- lpSolve::lp.transport(costs.mat, direction = 'min',
                           row.signs = rep("=", length(S)),
                           row.rhs = S,
                           col.signs = rep("=", length(R)),
                           col.rhs = R)$solution

  rownames(solution) <- names(S)
  colnames(solution) <- names(R)

  if (!bigmat) {
    return(solution)
  } else {
    bigres <- matrix(0, length(vals), length(vals), 
                     dimnames = list(labels, labels))
    bigres[names(S), names(R)] <- solution
    colnames(bigres) <- paste0("ship_to_", colnames(bigres))
    return(bigres)
  }
}
```

We can demo the function with your toy data to see how it works. Here I return just the small sender-receiver matrix. As we can see the solution is different to the one you supplied but also valid.

```r
get_transport_matrix(df$var, df$store, bigmat = FALSE)
#>   a b e
#> c 0 1 5
#> d 0 1 0
#> f 1 2 0
```

Using a linear programming package scales easily. Here for instance we solve for 10 stores:

```r
get_transport_matrix(c(-10:-1, 10:1), 
                     c(letters[1:10], letters[1:10]),
                     bigmat = FALSE)[1:6,]
#>   a b c d e f g h i j
#> a 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 2 1
#> b 0 0 0 0 4 5 0 0 0 0
#> c 0 0 0 6 2 0 0 0 0 0
#> d 0 0 6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> e 0 4 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> f 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Finally, the default output of the function is in a large-matrix format and you can simply
`cbind()` it to your dataframe to obtain your desired output:

```r
cbind(df, get_transport_matrix(df$var, df$store))
#>   store   sku var ship_to_a ship_to_b ship_to_c ship_to_d ship_to_e
#> a     a apple   1         0         0         0         0         0
#> b     b apple   4         0         0         0         0         0
#> c     c apple  -6         0         1         0         0         5
#> d     d apple  -1         0         1         0         0         0
#> e     e apple   5         0         0         0         0         0
#> f     f apple  -3         1         2         0         0         0
#>   ship_to_f
#> a         0
#> b         0
#> c         0
#> d         0
#> e         0
#> f         0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Bookmarked some articles about the linear programming transportation problem, interesting stuff. In the specific case I am working on; the costs to transport is not different per store as basically all products get shipped back to one a main warehouse before being 'divided' again.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there are simpler ways of doing this but this one works.
The function `fun` outputs a result `identical` to the expected one.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  n <- nrow(DF)
  mat <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  VAR <- DF[["var"]]
  neg <- which(DF[["var"]] < 0)
  for(k in neg){
    S <- 0
    Tot <- abs(DF[k, "var"])
    for(i in seq_along(VAR)){
      if(i != k){
        if(VAR[i] > 0){
          if(S + VAR[i] <= Tot){
            mat[k, i] <- VAR[i]
            S <- S + VAR[i]
            VAR[i] <- 0
          }else{
            mat[k, i] <- Tot - S
            S <- Tot
            VAR[i] <- VAR[i] - Tot + S
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  colnames(mat) <- paste0("ship_to_", DF[["store"]])
  cbind(DF, mat)
}

out <- fun(df)
identical(output, out)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Rui. Thanks for your answer! It works great on the sample set but not on my own dataset. I get the following error: "Error in mat[k, i] <- Tot - S : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix". All columns have the same classes and the dataframe has the same length.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360959/incorrect-number-of-subscripts-on-matrix-in-r. Just added as.data.frame(DF) to the function.

Comment: Responded too fast it seems. The function does not work properly in all the cases. Example: df <- data.frame(store = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),  sku = c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'), var = c(-44,-151,100,52,43)) Output has store B giving 100 apples to store C and store A 44 apples to C. That makes 144 instead of the 100 they should get.